# ncurses line-drawing not working on console

Tags: fonts, virtual-console, ncurses

When I try to use a curses-based program on a virtual console, the line and box drawing part are not working, as below in the display when running `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`. I'm using the the vga font, but I get the same result regardless of my font choice. When I do `showconsolefont` I can see the line drawing characters fine, it just won't work in ncurses programs. I also tried `pinentry-curses` which doesn't use colors and it has the same display problems. How can I fix curses on the console?

[image]

My terminal and locale on the console are:

```
TERM=linux
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I'm using the 15.04 beta:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Vivid Vervet (development branch)
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: What did you choose for the 'Encoding to use for the console' (the screen before the font selection)?

Comment: It is ISO-8859-15. I don't remember setting this myself, so I think it's the default after installation.

Comment: Try setting it to UTF-8

Comment: That worked after re-login! I must have misread and didn't even see the UTF-8 option before. Feel free to write as an answer and I'll approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a problem with the console's *encoding* rather than its font.

Run `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` again, but at the first screen select `UTF-8` before selecting your chosen font:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Download current version putty
[current version putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

If you use Putty, you need to update and enable as the picture shows.

[image: Enable VT100line drawing even in UTF-8 mode]

Comment: This was the answer for me: [ X]  Enable VT100 line drawing was needed